# Will Visual Composer and Bootstrap 4.0 work together?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, visual-composer

If I use any theme and include the newest Bootstrap framework 4.0, but I also want to have the plugin Visual Composer for some WYSIWYG editing, will they create a conflict? And if yes are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to checkout something like this plugin to make Visual Composer use bootstrap classes for columns and rows instead of its native classes.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/using-visual-composer-support-for-twitter-bootstrap-themes/

It is definitely possible as Themeforest sells themes with both.

https://themeforest.net/collections/4682897-themes-with-visual-composer-and-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. Bootstrap has [class *= "col-"] class displayed table cell, and visual composer has .vc-col-sm-12, which will read bootstrap class and will make conflict.
You can avoid that overwriting classes deppends on your needs.